# Update Navigation Drawer at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way how to update items in navigation drawer (jetpack compose) at runtime?
For example, I have Room database and for every record I want add a new item in navigation drawer. User will have an option to create a new record, after that I need to show updates in database immediately in navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out how to do it, use `MutableState` instead of basic `String`